# Using metal paint can as cover for non-IC rated recessed lights

Tags: insulation, attic, recessed-lighting

Do you think using a [1 gallon metal paint bucket](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-1-Gal-Metal-Paint-Bucket-and-Lid-96601/100038785#.UlfegBAzIyY) as a barrier in the attic over 3" non-IC rated recessed lighting will cause any heat problems?

I've been looking for ways to keep the blown in insulation away from my recessed cans that will also allow me to seal and insulate over them and thought this would be a cheap way to go. It seems safer to me than plastic or a hand made foam board box. I plan to use fire-rated caulking around the perimeter of the can to seal it to the attic floor and make it air tight. I'll probably slap some HVAC mastic on the can's seams for good measure and then insulate directly over the paint bucket.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** to causing heat problems, **No** to using a closed cover.

There is a 3" distance spec around such covers (to the sides), but the top must remain open for non-ic fixtures (to vent their heat).

Comment: Use A piece of 2' wide coil stock and tape to make a 10" circle.  Use this to keep insulation away and leave top open.

Comment: Or replace fixture with ic unit. Even if the unit is ic it might not be air tight(is an even more expensive option). So an airtight cavity still might needed.

Comment: @JustinK I'd favor air sealed, IC rated, as the best long term solution.

Comment: What's the diff between IC and non-IC that makes the IC version not have heat problems? Both use the same bulbs so how does an IC rated one solve the heat issue?

Comment: I think you'll find, for the same relative can size, the IC rated one has derated the bulb wattage somewhat.

Comment: So applying this logic one can simply use a smaller watt bulb in a non-IC light and would then be able to enclose it with an outer air-tight housing. I looked at an IC rated can up close and there is nothing special in it to deal with heat. There is simply an inner can and outer can. In fact the IC rated cans I saw have very little air space between the inner and outer can as compared to what a pain bucket would provide.

Comment: That logic is correct.  However, your assembly has not been tested as a unit, so it won't meet code. Also, some future owner would look at the wattage ratings on the can and *logically* conclude (in error) that higher wattage bulb could be used.

Comment: I thought the biggest difference from IC to non-IC cans is that IC cans contain a thermal switch as a fail safe to prevent over heating.